# Different (null) result upon compilation

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, static-linking

I have a C++ *(Qt)* project with a statically linked *(Non Qt, written by me)* library, which does some computation and a GUI application based on that library.

Half of the times when I compile the GUI application (which has the computation library statically linked) I receive null results.

If I clean and rebuild the entire project it works again.

I have absolutely no idea where this glitch comes from and I was looking for an explanation or at least guidance what and where to be looking for.

A bit more on how the library works:
An instance of a `Parameters` class is initiated and then passed as a pointer to the constructor of a `Computation` class.
It then has a method that does the computation itself based on the parameters contained in the `Parameters` and returns a `long double` result.

Thanks!

Comment: a minimal code example of the problem is needed before anyone can help you

Comment: I believe the problem is more theoretical than specific. And I also can't identify any erroneous code.

Comment: Sounds like uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have what appears to be intermittent memory corruption, run your program using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), which is available in most major Linux distributions.

For example:

```
valgrind ./my_binary
```

This will produce a (potentially) large log of memory leaks, overruns, uninitalised variables  or other invalid memory accesses, and importantly with line numbers and stack traces with the right options. including uninitialised variables as suggested by @MichaelWalz in the comments.

This may let you narrow down the problem is in your code or the library.

Comment: My problem was indeed caused by an uninitalised variable. Though I didn't manage to install `valgrind` on MacOS X I was able to isolate the error thanks to you explanation. Thank you!